# How can I register a (32-bit) COM DLL as a COM+ application

Tags: 32-vs-64-bit, com

I heard that you can register a 32 COM server DLL in COM+ so it will be executed as local server instead of an in-process server. This solves a 64/32 bit issue, it would be possible to access the 32-bit COM DLL in a 64 bit CScript host.

How do I register the DLL in Win7 "Component Services" as a COM+ application?

**Edit:**
The 32-Bit DLL can't be registered with the 64-Bit `regsvr32` since this 64-Bit program can't load the 32-Bit DLL as well as the CScript host. The only workaround is to make the in-process COM server in the DLL available in a out-of-process server running in a 32-Bit host. That's the reason to install the DLL in a COM+ application.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit version of Windows 7, there are two versions of the Regsv32.exe file:
The 64bit version is `%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe.`
The 32bit version is `%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe.`

To register the .dll, go to the respective path and run regsrv32.exe YourFileName.dll

Comment: The `regsvr32` programs load the 32-Bit DLL and calls `DllRegisterServer` that is exported by the DLL. Your proposal doesn't work, since the 64-Bit `regsvr32` isn't able to load the 32-Bit DLL. So your try to answer is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: You called the correct version of regsvr32 because this is the cortect answer

Comment: @Ramhound It's okay to registet a 32-bit DLL  with the 32-bit version of regsvr32. But this is neither an answer to the question how to call it from a64-bit process nor to the configuration of COM+.

Comment: @harper - Sure it is.  If you call the correct version of `regsvr32` then it isn't a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound And how would this be an answer to this question?

Comment: If you are not asking how to register a 32-bit dll on a 64-bit operating system then the question itself is not clear.  All you should have to do to register the dll in either case is register the dll with `regsvr32.exe`

Comment: I didn't asked how to register a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit OS but to register in COM+ or in "Component Services". That should be done in Control Panel.